# What's built-in bull detector

Tags: phrases

"Ernest Hemingway decided to write stories that spotlighted the harsh truth alive in this world, he said anybody trying to do that better have a built-in bull detector"
What is " built-in bull detector   "

Comment: It's a bowdlerized colloquialism; you need a built-in bull (feces) detector.

Answer (score 2):

In this context, **bull** is short for "bull shit", which is an expletive used for nonsense or lies.

Comment: Perfect for Hemingway who loved writing about bullshit and bulls.

Answer (score 0):

*Built-in bull detector* refers to a person's innate ability to detect bullshit: i.e. the innate ability to know when someone is lying or misrepresenting the truth so as to achieve his or her own goals.